# What's the difference between these where statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm doing

`Event.where(state: nil)` and get 1 result, but for `Event.where('state = ?', nil)` get 0 results.

What's the difference between these?

Comment: can you provide the sql output for each one? `.to_sql`

Comment: Ok, I see now. First gives `state IS NULL`, second `state = NULL`.

Comment: The equivalent query for the first one will be `Event.where('state IS NULL')`. `Event.where('state = ?', nil)` is not same as `Event.where(state: nil)`

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa Good question. I liked it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`where(state: nil)` evaluates to `WHERE events.state IS NULL` and other one evaluates to `WHERE (state = NULL)` in SQL.

Now, A `NULL` compared to anything returns `NULL`, except if you use `IS` operators.  So, if you want to check if it is `NULL` then use `state IS NULL`, if not `NULL` then `state IS NOT NULL`.

`state = NULL`, returns `NULL`, which, in `WHERE` clause, is equivalent to `FALSE`, that is why you got **0** records.

`events.state IS NULL` is the correct null comparisons so you got the output as you have in DB.

Answer (score 1):

They generate different sql.  When you have questions like this you can add a .to_sql to your relation and it will show you the sql that is generated and sent to the database.

Event.where(state: nil) produces this, which checks if x is a null like value

```
... WHERE events.state IS NULL
```

Event.where('state = ?', nil) produces this, which checks if X equals null which will never be true

```
... WHERE (state = NULL)
```